# Extracting lines from 2 files using AWK just return the last match

Tags: bash, awk

Im a bit new using AWK and im trying to print lines in a file1 that a specific field exists in a file2. I copied exactly examples that I found here but i dont know why its just printing only the last match of the file1.

**File1**

```
58000
72518
94850
```

**File2**

```
58000;123;abc
69982;456;rty
94000;576;ryt
94850;234;wer
84850;576;cvb
72518;345;ert
```

**Result Expected**

```
58000;123;abc
94850;234;wer
72518;345;ert
```

**What Im getting**

```
94850;234;wer
```

`awk -F';' 'NR==FNR{a[$1]++; next} $1 in a' file1 file2`

What im doing wrong?

Comment: Please do check if your files have control N characters. Do a `cat -v Input_file` once and see if you could see them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @RavinderSingh13!
The **file1** really had some hidden characters and I could see it using cat.

```
$ cat -v file1
58000^M
72518^M
94850^M
```

I removed using `sed -e "s/\r//g" file1` and the AWK worked perfectly.

Comment: no need for extra call to `sed` : just set **`RS = "\r?\n"`** in `awk` in the **`BEGIN { }`** section and it'll handle those `\r` for you seamlessly

Answer (score 3):

`awk` (while usable here), isn't the correct tool for the job. `grep` with the `-f` option is. The `-f file` option will read the patterns from `file` one per-line and search the input file for matches.

So in your case you want:

```
$ grep -f file1 file2
58000;123;abc
94850;234;wer
72518;345;ert
```

(**note:** I removed the trailing `'\'` from the data file, replace it if it wasn't a typo)

---

**Using awk**

If you did want to rewrite what `grep` is doing using `awk`, that is fairly simple. Just read the contents of `file1` into an array and then for processing records from the second file, just check if field-1 is in the array, if so, print the record (default action), e.g.

```
$ awk -F';' 'FNR==NR {a[$1]=1; next} $1 in a' file1 file2
58000;123;abc
94850;234;wer
72518;345;ert
```

(same note about the trailing slash)

Comment: about the grep part : with your current solution there could be matching lines because of a substring (e.g: file1 contains `123`, and file2 has a line with id `91239`), or because of another field (file1 contains `123`, file2 has a line `456;123`). A fix could be to turn all lines to `^{xxx};`. A convoluted one liner could be : `grep -f <(sed -e 's/^/^/' -e 's/$/;/' file1) file2`.

Comment: @LeGEC quite true, there are limitations to all solutions. Another way to tighten it up would be with the `-w` whole-word option.